# How to make commands for discord bot non-case sensitive

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
//ignore 1 up and 1 down
const client = new Discord.Client();
//prefix 
const prefix = `+`;
//log for me
client.once(`ready`, () => {
    console.log("IM POWERED UP")
});


//commands

client.on(`message`, message =>{
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.lengh).split(/ +/);

    //Username..(embed)
    if (message.content === `${prefix}Username`){
        let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
        let args = message.content.split(` `);
        let command = messageArray[1].toLowerCase();
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`user information`)
        .addField(`Your Username is`, message.author.username)
        .addField(`Bugs`, `To report bugs please go to TxPsycho#1080 and you may earn a reward!`)
        .setThumbnail(message.author.displayAvatarURL())
        .setFooter(`Wanna get Valorant cheats? Join here`)
        .setColor(`RANDOM`)
        message.channel.send(embed);
    }
    
    //help command
    if (message.content === `${prefix}Help`){
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(`Help`)
        .addField(`A list of commands are below!`)
        .setThumbnail(message.author.displayAvatarURL())
        .setDescription(`AMOTHERFUCKINGTESTYOUMOTHERFUCKAYOUTHINKITSFUNNYCALLINGAT2AM`)
        .setColor(`RANDOM`)
        message.channel.send(embed);
    }
});


//ignore this and leave it at bottom
client.login(`Nz`)
```

> I am not sure how to make the commands caps insensitive, this is the error it’s been giving me. I have been searching but found no information. Down below is the link to an error that I have been receiving when I try to debug the code.

[Click here to see the error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOs52.png)

Comment: Arrays are zero indexed, aka start at 0

Answer (score 1):

Like rogue said the issue is calling toLowerCase on undefined here:

`let command = messageArray[1].toLowerCase();`

The real command would be at 0, since arrays are 0 indexed

You might want to `shift` it instead so you can get the args easier:

Message: `!help 12 24 36`

```js
const args = message.content.split(" ");
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

console.log(args);
// => [12, 24, 36]

console.log(args[0]);
// => 12
```

After that you just compare `command` instead of message.content:

```js
if(command === "!help") {


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sanitise messages with [toLowerCase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)

```
console.log('ALPHABET'.toLowerCase()); // 'alphabet'
console.log('aLPhABeT'.toLowerCase()); // 'alphabet'
console.log('alphabet'.toLowerCase()); // 'alphabet'
```

Comment: This is true, but the OP is already attempting that in his code. His real problem is he's attempting to call `#toLowerCase` on `undefined`